# Ansible on a linux like OS answer a question I need to answer with yes

Tags: ansible, ansible-module

I have a DataDomain System which I can enter via ssh. I need to automate a procedure on the DataDomain which does aks a question after a command:

```
storage add tier active dev3

Object-store is not enabled. Filesystem will use block storage for user data.
    Do you want to continue? (yes|no) [no]: yes
```

I do try this with Ansible and do use the raw module

```
- name:  add dev3 active tier
  raw: storage add tier active dev3
  register: RESULT
```

This is failing with:

```
TASK [add dev3 active tier] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [3.127.218.96]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 9, "stderr": "Shared connection to 3.127.218.96 closed.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["Shared connection to 3.127.218.96 closed."], "stdout": "\r\n**** Could not add storage: system capacity exceeds the limit allowable by the license.\r\n\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["", "**** Could not add storage: system capacity exceeds the limit allowable by the license.", ""]}
```

the following ansible-playbook is also failing with:

```
- name:  add dev3 active tier
  raw: | 
    yes | storage add tier active dev3
  register: RESULT
```

expect module does not accept raw and is also failing.

```
 - name expect for add dev3 active tier
      expect:
        raw: storage add tier active dev3
        responses:
          Question:
            - Do you want to continue? (yes|no) [no]: y
        timeout: 30 
      register: RESULT
```

Any idea how I can catch the question and answer with yes?

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your `expect` task is coming from two things:

First, the fact that:

> The question, or key, under responses is a python regex match.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html#notes*</sup>

So you will have to escape each and every symbol that might have a meaning in a regex.
In your case those symbols are `?`, `(`, `|`, `)`, `[` and `]`.
<sup>*Note: those kind or behaviour are easily testable in regex tools like this one: https://regex101.com/r/ubtVfH/1/*</sup>

Second, the `responses` key have two format that you mixed here.

- Either you have

  ```yaml
  responses:
      Question:
        - response1
        - response2
        - response3
  ```

  Where you don't specify a question from the script but rather a sequential list of answers. This will, of course, only work if the question and responses always comes in the same order.
- Either you use

  ```yaml
  responses:
    This is the prompt of the question in the script: that is the answer
    This is another question: and here is the corresponding answer
  ```

  And here you are sure you map correctly each answer to the corresponding question. Mind there is no `Question` key in this dictionary and that the answers are the keys of a dictionary, and not a list.

---

So for your use case, the proper use of expect would be:

```yaml
- expect:
    command: storage add tier active dev3
    responses:
      Do you want to continue\? \(yes\|no\) \[no\]: 'yes'
    timeout: 30 
  register: result
```

Answer (score 0):

The `yes` command sends a `y` by default. But your command is expecting a `yes`. You can pass the string for `yes` command to repeat.

```yaml
- name: add dev3 active tier
  shell:
    cmd: yes yes | storage add tier active dev3
  register: RESULT
```